# Notification without email

Tags: python, django, email, notifications, django-notification

I am implementing a website using django and I want to allow users to decide if they want to receive emails or not. Is it possible to customize django-notification such that it doesn't send emails to some users? I can change the original app but I prefer to preserve it as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you wish to modify django-notification? There is a model called `NoticeSetting` which indicates whether a message needs to be sent to a user (see [here](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/blob/master/notification/models.py#L58)). This model is used by the function `should_send` at [line 315](https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/blob/master/notification/models.py#L325). That means you can implement the desired functionality without customizing django-notification.